# HOW TO CORRECT THE SPELLING OF MY USERNAME

Tags: user

While installing Elementary 6 in VirtualBox (host is Ubuntu 20.04), inadvertently I made a typing mistake in my name as user - ANUPAM became AMUPAM. How to rectify the spelling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name of the user account is wrong, the best way to change it is to create a *new* user account, grant it admin privileges, and log in with the new account.

1. Open "Settings"
2. Find "User Accounts" (near the bottom) and open:
   [image: Settings - User Accounts]
3. Click the little "+" in the lower-left corner to create a new account
4. Set the details, ensuring that your account is set as "Administrator" (so that you can perform updates and run commands with `sudo`)
   [image: Add User]
5. Press "Create User"
6. Sign out of your current account
7. Sign into your new account
8. Configure the new account as you would like
9. *(Optional)* Delete the old account

Comment: Many many thanks. With your help I have created the correct New User Account. But primarily I was not able to delete the old account. However, ultimately that too could be done with the help from the following link. https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-safely-delete-a-user-account-on-linux/

Comment: Glad it has worked for you. Could you click the checkmark beside the answer (and maybe the up arrow) if you found it helpful?

Comment: Why not? Did it.